# PHP doesn't echo to Ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send email with PHP using an Ajax request, but my "echo" on the PHP file just seems to not work and I have no idea why.

Thinking that my PHP code was wrong, I replaced my code with just an "echo" as posted below, but it still is not working.

I'm posting my HTML, JS, PHP and also the firebug response, which I don't quite understand.

HTML

```
<form id="contactForm" class="contact-form">
    <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
         <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome" type="text" required title="Por favor, preencha esse campo." x-moz-errormessage="Por favor, preencha esse campo."/>
         <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required title="Por favor, preencha esse campo corretamente." x-moz-errormessage="Por favor, preencha esse campo corretamente.">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Qual sua mensagem?" rows="10" required title="Por favor, preencha esse campo." x-moz-errormessage="Por favor, preencha esse campo.">  </textarea>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
       <a id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar Email" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar Email</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label id="labelResposta" style="font-size: 22px; margin-top: 20px; display: none;">Email enviado com sucesso!</label>
    </div>
    <div id="messages"></div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#btnEnviar').click(function() {

    $('#btnEnviar').html('Enviando...');
    $('#btnEnviar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    var formData = {
        nome: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        message: $('#message').val()
    };
    // console.log(formData);
    // console.log($("#contactForm").serialize());

    if(!formData.nome) {
        $('#btnEnviar').html('Enviar Email');
        $('#btnEnviar').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#labelResposta').html('Por favor preencha seu nome.');
        $('#labelResposta').fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#labelResposta').fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    } else if(!formData.email) {
        $('#btnEnviar').html('Enviar Email');
        $('#btnEnviar').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#labelResposta').html('Por favor preencha seu email.');
        $('#labelResposta').fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#labelResposta').fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    } else if(!formData.message) {
        $('#btnEnviar').html('Enviar Email');
        $('#btnEnviar').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#labelResposta').html('Por favor preencha sua mensagem.');
        $('#labelResposta').fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#labelResposta').fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    } else {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'file:///home/phellipe/Desktop/projetos/phperin/email/email_processor.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#btnEnviar').html('Enviar Email');
                $('#btnEnviar').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#labelResposta').html('Email enviado com sucesso!');
                $('#labelResposta').fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#labelResposta').fadeOut();
                }, 3000);
            },
            error: function(x, e){
                console.log(x);
                console.log(e);
                if(x.status==0){
                    $('#labelResposta').html('Você não está online!\n Por favor, verifique sua conexão.');
                }else if(x.status==404){
                    $('#labelResposta').html('URL não encontrada.');
                }else if(x.status==500){
                    $('#labelResposta').html('Erro interno.');
                }else if(e=='parsererror'){
                    $('#labelResposta').html('Erro de parse.');
                }else if(e=='timeout'){
                    $('#labelResposta').html('Timeout.');
                }else {
                    $('#labelResposta').html('Erro desconhecido.\n'+x.responseText);
                }
                $('#btnEnviar').html('Enviar Email');
                $('#btnEnviar').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#labelResposta').fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#labelResposta').fadeOut();
                }, 3000);
            }
        });

    }

    return false;
});
```

PHP (test)

```
<?php echo "string"; ?>
```

PHP (real)

```
<?php

$sender_name = trim(ucfirst($_REQUEST['nome']));
$sender_email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
$sender_message = trim(ucfirst($_REQUEST['message']));

$html_email = '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PhPerin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
          <p>Olá</p>
          <p>Notificamos que <em>' . $sender_name . '</em> entrou em contato</p>
          <p>Deixou a seguinte mensagem:</p>
          <p>' . $sender_message . '</p>
          <p>Você pode entrar em contato pelo seguinte email <a href="mailto:' . $sender_email . '" class="contact">' . $sender_email . '</a></p>

    </body>
    </html>';

require_once("send_email.php");

echo "string";
?>
```

Firebug Response

```
readyState  4
responseText    "<?php echo "string"; ?>"
status  200
statusText  "parsererror"
```

Comment: if your getting `<?php` back then the file is processing the php

Comment: Nice, but why isn't the php echoing? Any idea?

Comment: your running an actual web server?

Comment: Ok, I'm felling really stupid right now. I've been searching answers for almost 2 hours now, and my code just wasn't on a PHP server. Thanks man, really appreciated!

Comment: when i visit Brazil, im staying at your place ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if you need to escape those double quotes.  Where it says

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

try

```
<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
```